# Dynamic custom calendar in flutter

Tags: flutter

i want to show calendar like shown in image on week basis. show week dates from sun to sat and display the dates. On left click show past week and on right click show next week dates. also i require to get week's start date and end date.

i have tried using some plugins in flutter , but i didnt get what i want so now i want to create dynamically custom calendar in flutter.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
The following is modification of package https://pub.dev/packages/g2x_week_calendar 
You can get week start with `MyDateTime.getFirstDateOfWeek`
code snippet

```
class MyDateTime {
  static String formatDate(DateTime date, {String format = "dd/MM/yyyy"}) {
    var str = format.replaceAll(
        "dd", (date.day < 10 ? "0" : "") + date.day.toString());
    str = str.replaceAll(
        "MM", (date.month < 10 ? "0" : "") + date.month.toString());
    str = str.replaceAll("yyyy", date.year.toString());
    return str;
  }

  ///get first date of week
  static DateTime getFirstDateOfWeek(DateTime date) {
    return date.weekday == 7 ? date : date.add(Duration(days: -date.weekday));
  }
... 
G2xSimpleWeekCalendar(
      100.0,
      DateTime.now(),
      dateCallback: (date) => _dateCallback(date),
      typeCollapse: true,
      //backgroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
    ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyDateTime {
  static String formatDate(DateTime date, {String format = "dd/MM/yyyy"}) {
    var str = format.replaceAll(
        "dd", (date.day < 10 ? "0" : "") + date.day.toString());
    str = str.replaceAll(
        "MM", (date.month < 10 ? "0" : "") + date.month.toString());
    str = str.replaceAll("yyyy", date.year.toString());
    return str;
  }

  ///get first date of week
  static DateTime getFirstDateOfWeek(DateTime date) {
    return date.weekday == 7 ? date : date.add(Duration(days: -date.weekday));
  }

  ///get all days of week
  static List<int> getDaysOfWeek(DateTime date) {
    var firstDay = getFirstDateOfWeek(date);
    var days = <int>[];
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      days.add(firstDay.add(Duration(days: i)).day);
    }
    return days;
  }
}

typedef void DateCallback(DateTime val);

class G2xSimpleWeekCalendar extends StatefulWidget {
  G2xSimpleWeekCalendar(
    this.bodyHeight,
    this.currentDate, {
    this.strWeekDays = const [
      "Sun",
      "Mon",
      "Tues",
      "Wed",
      "Thurs",
      "Fri",
      "Sat"
    ],
    this.format = "yyyy/MM/dd",
    this.dateCallback,
    this.defaultTextStyle = const TextStyle(),
    this.selectedTextStyle = const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
    this.selectedBackgroundDecoration = const BoxDecoration(),
    this.backgroundDecoration = const BoxDecoration(),
    this.typeCollapse = false,
  });
  final DateTime currentDate;
  final List<String> strWeekDays;
  final String format;
  final DateCallback dateCallback;
  //style
  final TextStyle defaultTextStyle;
  final TextStyle selectedTextStyle;
  final BoxDecoration selectedBackgroundDecoration;
  final BoxDecoration backgroundDecoration;
  final bool typeCollapse;
  final double bodyHeight;
  @override
  _G2xSimpleWeekCalendarState createState() => _G2xSimpleWeekCalendarState();
}

class _G2xSimpleWeekCalendarState extends State<G2xSimpleWeekCalendar>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  DateTime currentDate;
  var weekDays = <int>[];
  var selectedIndex = 0;
  var _close = false;

  //Collapse
  AnimationController _collapseController;
  Animation<double> _collpseAnimation;
  var _heightCollapse = 0.0;

  _setSelectedDate(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedIndex = index;
      currentDate =
          MyDateTime.getFirstDateOfWeek(currentDate).add(Duration(days: index));
      if (widget.dateCallback != null) widget.dateCallback(currentDate);
    });
  }

  _altertWeek(int days) {
    setState(() {
      currentDate = currentDate.add(Duration(days: days));
      if (widget.dateCallback != null) widget.dateCallback(currentDate);
    });
  }

  _collapse() {
    if (!widget.typeCollapse) return;
    if (_collapseController.status == AnimationStatus.completed && _close) {
      _collapseController.reverse();
      _close = false;
    } else if (_collapseController.status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
      _collapseController.forward();
      _close = true;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentDate = widget.currentDate;
    // if(widget.dateCallback != null)
    //   widget.dateCallback(currentDate);
    selectedIndex = currentDate.weekday == 7 ? 0 : currentDate.weekday;

    //Collapse
    _heightCollapse = widget.bodyHeight;
    _collapseController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    _collpseAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: widget.bodyHeight, end: 0)
        .animate(_collapseController);
    _collapseController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _heightCollapse = _collpseAnimation.value;
      });
      if (_collapseController.status == AnimationStatus.completed && !_close) {
        _collapseController.reset();
        _close = false;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    weekDays = MyDateTime.getDaysOfWeek(currentDate);
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var sizePart = size.width / 4 - 10;
    var rowWeeks = Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            decoration: widget.backgroundDecoration,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 5, right: 5),
            child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      width: sizePart * 2,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                              MyDateTime.formatDate(currentDate,
                                  format: widget.format),
                              style: widget.defaultTextStyle),
                        ],
                      )),
                ])),
        Container(
            //height: _heightCollapse,
            decoration: widget.backgroundDecoration,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5, left: 5, right: 5),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () => _altertWeek(-7),
                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_left,
                      color: widget.defaultTextStyle.color),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: widget.strWeekDays.map((i) {
                        return InkWell(
                            onTap: () =>
                                _setSelectedDate(widget.strWeekDays.indexOf(i)),
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              decoration:
                                  selectedIndex == widget.strWeekDays.indexOf(i)
                                      ? widget.selectedBackgroundDecoration
                                      : BoxDecoration(),
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(i,
                                      style: selectedIndex ==
                                              widget.strWeekDays.indexOf(i)
                                          ? widget.selectedTextStyle
                                          : widget.defaultTextStyle),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 2,
                                  ),
                                  selectedIndex == widget.strWeekDays.indexOf(i)
                                      ? CircleAvatar(
                                          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                                          child: Text(
                                              weekDays[widget.strWeekDays
                                                      .indexOf(i)]
                                                  .toString(),
                                              style: selectedIndex ==
                                                      widget.strWeekDays
                                                          .indexOf(i)
                                                  ? widget.selectedTextStyle
                                                  : widget.defaultTextStyle))
                                      : Text(
                                          weekDays[
                                                  widget.strWeekDays.indexOf(i)]
                                              .toString(),
                                          style: selectedIndex ==
                                                  widget.strWeekDays.indexOf(i)
                                              ? widget.selectedTextStyle
                                              : widget.defaultTextStyle),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ));
                      }).toList()),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () => _altertWeek(7),
                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_right,
                      color: widget.defaultTextStyle.color),
                )
              ],
            ))
      ],
    );
    return rowWeeks;
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DateTime dateCallback;

  _dateCallback(DateTime date) {
    dateCallback = date;
    print(dateCallback);
  }

  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            G2xSimpleWeekCalendar(
              100.0,
              DateTime.now(),
              dateCallback: (date) => _dateCallback(date),
              typeCollapse: true,
              //backgroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```